# Unable to locate the right path for include file in s3 server

Tags: php, amazon-s3

In my index.php I include a file to initiate first level pop up like this,

```
<?php include('profile.php');?>
```

In the profile.php, I include second level file like this:

```
<?php include("posts.php");?>//means both profile.php and posts.php reside in the same directory.However the second level pop up box doesn't appear and it says 'content not found' error.
```

WHen I viewed the source of the page in the browser, content not loaded from the line where object is instantiated: `$details = new searchItems(); Probably the class path is not defined due to wrong path error for the file which contained the class to instantiate the object.

But I wonder, why it can work absolutely fine on localhost and not on S3?`How do I define the path correctly to suit s3 server?

posts.php

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php # include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'config.php');?>
<?php #include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'class.search_functions.php');?>
<?php
//echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
?>
<?php
$details = new searchItems();
$receiveDetails = $details->getTutorPosts($_SESSION['user_id']);

?>
<section id="posts-popup" class="mfp-hide white-popup">
 <!--main category starts-->
 <?php
    foreach($receiveDetails as $k=>$v){?>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns myposts">
    <div class="small-12 medium-8 large-8 columns">
        <?php
        $date = strtotime($v['dateposted']);
        $formatedDate = date("j F Y", $date);
        ?>
        <?php echo $formatedDate;?><br/>
         <?php echo $v['catname'];?> > <?php echo $v['subject'];?><br/>
        <?php echo $v['rate'];?>

    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns">
    <div class="fb-share-button" 
        data-href="http://www.facebook.com/TheGloopal" 
        data-layout="button_count">
    </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">
        <input type="button" value="delete" name="delete" class="<?php echo $v['postId'];?>" id="">
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns">
        <input type="button" value="delete" name="delete2" class="delete2" id="<?php echo $v['postId'];?>">
        </div>
         <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns">
        <input type="button" value="Keep" name="nodelete" class="keep_<?php echo $v['postId'];?>" id="">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <?php
        }
        ?>
<!--content ends-->
 <a href="#profile-popup" class="details-popup-link">go back</a>
 </section>
```

Comment: What happens when you use `$_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as the root of your include path? `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/profile.php'` and same for posts

Comment: @Terminus,I tried this earlier but doesn't work. I tried to hardcode the class called from the object in the posts.php in that page itself and found that it works.

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? Could you post the  message without revealing too much personal info?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question. What's being stored on S3 here exactly? How are you accessing it?